# Oracle SQL when querying a range of data

Tags: function, plsql, oracle11g

I have a table that for an ID, will have data in several bucket fields.  I want a function to pull out a sum of buckets, but the function parameters will include the start and end bucket field.

So, if I had a table like this:

```
ID   Bucket0  Bucket30  Bucket60  Bucket90  Bucket120
10       5.00    12.00     10.00       0.0       8.00
```

If I send in the ID and the parameters Bucket0, Bucket0, it would return only the value in the Bucket0 field: 5.00

If I send in the ID and the parameters Bucket30, Bucket120, it would return the sum of the buckets from 30 to 120, or (12+10+0+8) 30.00.

Is there a nicer way to write this other than a huge ugly

```
if parameter1=bucket0 and parameter2=bucket0 
    then select bucket0
else if parameter1=bucket0 and parameter2=bucket1 
    then select bucket0 + bucket1
else if parameter1=bucket0 and parameter2=bucket2 
    then select bucket0 + bucket1 + bucket2
```

and so on?

The table already exists, so I don't have a lot of control over that.  I can make my parameters for the function however I want.  I can safely say that if a set of buckets are wanted, none in the middle will be skipped, so specifying start and end buckets would work.  I could have a single comma delimited string of all buckets wanted.

Comment: Looking for nice ways will not be very fruitful when your database design is wanting. Your bucket columns should not have been separate columns. Instead you should have two columns: `bucket` and `bucket_id`, and have more rows.

Comment: @trincot Perhaps so, but as I said, I don't have control over that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have been better if your table had been normalised, like this:

```
id | bucket    | value
---+-----------+------
10 | bucket000 |  5
10 | bucket030 | 12
10 | bucket060 | 10
10 | bucket090 |  0
10 | bucket120 |  8
```

Also, the buckets should better have names that are easy to compare in ranges, so that `bucket030` comes between `bucket000` and `bucket120` in the normal alphabetical order, which is not the case if you leave out the padded zeroes.

If the above normalisation is not possible, then use an `unpivot` clause to turn your current table into the structure depicted above:

```
select id, sum(value)
from (
        select *
        from mytable 
        unpivot (value for bucket_id in (bucket0   as 'bucket000', 
                                         bucket30  as 'bucket030', 
                                         bucket60  as 'bucket060',
                                         bucket90  as 'bucket090',
                                         bucket120 as 'bucket120'))
     ) normalised
where bucket_id between 'bucket000' and 'bucket060'
group by id
```

When you do this with parameter variables, make sure those parameters have the padded zeroes as well.

You could for instance ensure that as follows for *parameter1*:

```
if parameter1 like 'bucket%' then
    parameter1 := 'bucket' || lpad(+substr(parameter1, 7), 3, '0');
end if;
```

...etc.